# Install Django-CMS on a separate system user

Tags: linux, django, postgresql, ubuntu, django-cms

I am new to Django CMS and Ubuntu. I would like to install Django-CMS on a separate system user on Ubuntu, so that my python environment dedicated to Django-CMS would not conflict with other python development work I do on my system. Plus it should make it easier for me to get rid(uninstall) of my Django-CMS environment easily from my machine. Is there a How to anyone knows for this?

Comment: This would be better to ask on askubuntu.com. It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) rather than setting up separate user accounts.

Comment: seconded, that's my advice too